# Regex for date no spaces

Tags: regex, vb.net

how do I validate a date in the form 011118(dd/mm/yy)? I have found solutions for dates but they include spaces / . etc

Comment: This code works fine for leap year. but uses / . and is mm/dd/yy

Comment: `If DateTime.TryParseExact(s, "dMyy", Nothing, DateTimeStyles.None, New DateTime) Then ' it's a valid date`. Or use `ddMMyy` if two digits are *required* for the day and month.

Comment: Why do you need Regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex: `^(?:(?:(?:0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])|(?:29|30)(?:0[13-9]|1[0-2])|31(?:0[13578]|1[02]))[1-9]\d{1}|2902(?:(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|00))$`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/63JoRX/3)

Comment: Thankyou how do I make this ddmmyy?

Comment: When you put 130517 it doesnt work as its in the form mmddyy